# UInt32 array to String Byte Array in Swift

Tags: swift, swift4

Before I start I would like to apologise if I say something crazy.

I am working on an app that implements a c library. Among others, It shares idArrays.

I have the part decodes an idArray and it was given to me:

```
func decodeArrayID(aArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>, aTokenLen:UInt32)->([UInt32], String){

    let arrayCount = Int(aTokenLen / 4)
    var idArrayTemp = [UInt32]()
    var idArrayStringTemp = ""

    for i in 0..<arrayCount{

        let idValue = decodeArrayIDItem(index: i, array: aArray)

        idArrayTemp.append(idValue)
        idArrayStringTemp += "\(idValue) "

    }

    return (idArrayTemp, idArrayStringTemp)
}

func decodeArrayIDItem(index:Int, array:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>) -> UInt32{

    var value:UInt32 = UInt32(array[index * 4]) & 0xFF

    value <<= 8
    value |= UInt32(array [index * 4 + 1]) & 0xFF
    value <<= 8
    value |= UInt32(array [index * 4 + 2]) & 0xFF
    value <<= 8
    value |= UInt32(array [index * 4 + 3]) & 0xFF


    return value

}
```

As we can see the idArray is send through UnsafeMutablePointer AKA UnsafeMutablePointer.

Now I am working with the encoding part. The function will take an array of UInt32 values and will try to convert it into byte array and will convert into a sting for sending it through the library.

So far I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
func encodeIDArray(idArray:[UInt32])->String{

    var aIDArray8:[UInt8] = [UInt8]()

    for var value in idArray{

        let count = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
        let bytePtr = withUnsafePointer(to: &value) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count) {
                UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: count)
            }
        }

        aIDArray8 += Array(bytePtr)
    }

    let stringTest = String(data: Data(aIDArray8), encoding: .utf8)

    return stringTest!

}
```

A test result for the input [1,2] returns "\u{01}\0\0\0\u{02}\0\0\0" and something tells is not quite right...

Thank you

**Edited**
 The c functions are

```
DllExport void STDCALL DvProviderAvOpenhomeOrgPlaylist1EnableActionIdArray(THandle aProvider, CallbackPlaylist1IdArray aCallback, void* aPtr);
```

where CallbackPlaylist1IdArray is

```
typedef int32_t (STDCALL *CallbackPlaylist1IdArray)(void* aPtr, IDvInvocationC* aInvocation, void* aInvocationPtr, uint32_t* aToken, char** aArray, uint32_t* aArrayLen);
```

and the value to aArray is the value that get the Byte array

Comment: `Data(aIDArray8)` contains the correct bytes (01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00), but converting that to a *string* makes no sense (and can easily fail for arbitrary data).

Comment: ok. I understand. The array needs to be send as a UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>? How can I achieve that in swift?

Comment: So you need to pass the data to a C function? How is that function defined?

Comment: Yes, please see my updated answer

Comment: So you call DvProviderAvOpenhomeOrgPlaylist1EnableActionIdArray(), and have to implement the callback in Swift?

Comment: I cannot see where you want to use `encodeIDArray(idArray:)` . `CallbackPlaylist1IdArray` is a callback type which you need to implement. You may need something like `decodeArrayID` in the implementation, but no need to use `encodeIDArray(idArray:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the `[UInt32]` array values to the allocated memory without creating an intermediate `[Int8]` array, and use the `bigEndian`
property instead of bit shifting and masking:

```
func writeCArrayValue(from pointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?,
                      withUInt32Values array: [UInt32]){

    pointer?.pointee = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size * array.count)
    pointer?.pointee?.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: array.count) {
        for i in 0..<array.count {
            $0[i] = array[i].bigEndian
        }
    }
}
```

In the same way you can do the decoding:

```
func decodeArrayID(aArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>, aTokenLen:UInt32)->[UInt32] {

    let arrayCount = Int(aTokenLen / 4)
    var idArrayTemp = [UInt32]()

    aArray.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: arrayCount) {
        for i in 0..<arrayCount {
            idArrayTemp.append(UInt32(bigEndian: $0[i]))
        }
    }
    return idArrayTemp
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Although it is great, is no compatible with the decode function.

Comment: Sorry. It works! I had a typo. I will make some test and I will let you know and possible i will accept

Comment: Great answer! Do you know if the decode function can be do by doing the same principle?

Comment: Thank you very much. Nice and simple ;)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are in the right way

```
func encodeIDArray(idArray:[UInt32])->String{

    var aIDArray8:[UInt8] = [UInt8]()

    for var value in idArray{

        let count = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size
        let bytePtr = withUnsafePointer(to: &value) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: count) { v in
                //Just change it to don't return the pointer itself, but the result of the rebound
                UnsafeBufferPointer(start: v, count: count)
            }
        }

        aIDArray8 += Array(bytePtr)
    }

    let stringTest = String(data: Data(aIDArray8), encoding: .utf8)

    return stringTest!

}
```

Change your test to a some valid value in ASCII Table like this

```
encodeIDArray(idArray: [65, 66, 67])   // "ABC"
```

I hope it help you... Good luck and let me know it it works on your case.

Comment: Thank you for answer, it still prints "\u{01}\0\0\0\u{02}\0\0\0\u{03}\0\0\0" for [1,2] .

Comment: This values aren't valid values for string. Check the ASCII table or change your strategy if you're transferring  an array of raw bytes instead of an array of string convertible bytes.

Comment: Sorry maybe was my fault but the idea is to get an array of UInt32 ID's a transform them into a Byte array. These ID's go from 1 to 1024

Comment: If your IDs go from 1 to 1024 why don't you use an array of UInt16s instead? That would let you save values from 0 to 65535  (0  -> 2¹⁶-1)

Comment: I use this method to turn UInt16 array to UInt8 array. It gave some non alphaNumeric characters. After I remove them I reached desired string.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a binary buffer to a string and expect it to work. You should base64 encode your binary data. That IS a valid way to represent binary data as strings.

Consider the following code:

```
//Utility function that takes a typed pointer to a data buffer an converts it to an array of the desired type of object
func convert<T>(count: Int, data: UnsafePointer<T>) -> [T] {
    let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: data, count: count);
    return Array(buffer)
}

//Create an array of UInt32 values
let intArray: [UInt32] = Array<UInt32>(1...10)
print("source arrray = \(intArray)")
let arraySize = MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size * intArray.count

//Convert the array to a Data object
let data = Data(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer(intArray),
                count: arraySize)

//Convert the binary Data to base64
let base64String = data.base64EncodedString()

print("Array as base64 data = ", base64String)
if let newData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
    newData.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt32>)->Void in
        let newArray = convert(count:10, data: bytes)
        print("After conversion, newArray = ", newArray)
    }
} else {
    fatalError("Failed to base-64 decode data!")
}
```

The output of that code is:

```
source arrray =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Array as base64 data =  AQAAAAIAAAADAAAABAAAAAUAAAAGAAAABwAAAAgAAAAJAAAACgAAAA==
After conversion, newArray =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Use the Data function `Data.base64EncodedString()` to convert **to** base64 encoding, and `Data(base64Encoded:)` to convert from a base64 string into a `Data` object

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I provided working code that will convert an array of `UInt32` values back and forth to a Base64 string.

Comment: Note that the binary representation of any scalar value bigger than Int8/UInt8 will be different on little-endian or big-endian devices, so it is hardware-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Although I really appreciate all the answers I have finally figured out what was happening. I have to say that Duncan's answer was the closest to my problem.

So far I have interpreted char** as String. Turns out that it can be also a pointer to an array (Correct me if I am Wrong!). Converting the array as String gave a format that the library didn't like and it could not be decode on the other end.

The way I ended up doing is:

```
func encodeIDArray(idArray:[UInt32])->[Int8]{

    var aIDArray8 = [UInt8].init(repeating: 0, count: idArray.count*4)

    for i in 0..<idArray.count{

        aIDArray8[i * 4] = UInt8(idArray[i] >> 24) & 0xff
        aIDArray8[i * 4 + 1] = UInt8(idArray[i] >> 16) & 0xff
        aIDArray8[i * 4 + 2] = UInt8(idArray[i] >> 8) & 0xff
        aIDArray8[i * 4 + 3] = UInt8(idArray[i]) & 0xff

    }

    return aIDArray8.map { Int8(bitPattern: $0) }

}
```

and then I am assigning the value of the C Variable in swift like that:

```
let myArray = encodeIDArray(idArray:theArray)
writeCArrayValue(from: aArrayPointer, withValue: myArray)

func writeCArrayValue(from pointer:UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?, withValue array:[Int8]){

    pointer?.pointee = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: array.count)
    memcpy(pointer?.pointee, array, array.count)

}
```

aArrayPointer is a the char** used by the library.